# Which javascript framework to use with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, ember.js

I recently started using twitter bootstrap and it has a great collection of UI components. I wanted to use it in a project but when I started searching for a javascript framework to work along side twitter bootstrap, I was confused between what gels well with bootstrap - angularjs, backbonejs or emberjs.

I am a beginner in all three but I have worked with some jQuery before, so I am open to trying out any of these. Any suggestions on which javascript framework integrates well with Bootstrap?

Thanks.

Comment: i will suggest Angular js

Comment: you should really watch this: http://vimeo.com/73913825

Comment: Thanks everyone. I didn't know that it would be opinion-based, hence downvoted. Have enough info - will play around with what's mentioned in the answers and see what fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the application you are building. I would select

1. `AngularJS` if the application is data driven. Angular JS is good in 2 way binding. But keep in mind the learning curve for AngularJS for most of the developers is steep.
2. `backbone.js` if I need to do rigrous DOM manipulation.

*Ember and Angular are very similar. However there are more angular developers in the community. So I would go with Angular.*

For detailed explanation [visit](http://readwrite.com/2014/02/06/angular-backbone-ember-best-javascript-framework-for-you#awesm=~oyh4jSQdDTRrgf)

Comment: I'd say that to get started with a simple app with two-way-binding and some services, is really easy with Angular, that's the point of it. On the other hand, when building heavier web apps it becomes a bit trickier. I started with Angular in beginning of the year, and I come from a Java background, and I think it's really straight forward when you get a hold of the different parts of the framework and how Model-View-Controller works. Directives are the hardest and probably the most messy part of Angular at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

there are some bootstrap module for angularjs they are [ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) and [angular-strap](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap)...

if you decide to use angularjs which you should prefer in my opinion you can use these module so easy...